# Does one need to tovel enamelware?

Tags: halacha, tevilas-keilim-dipping, home-house

Does one need to tovel keilim that are indicated as being made of "enamelware"? Should a bracha accompany the tevila?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Star-K website](http://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/1168/the-mitzvah-of-tevilas-keilim):

> Utensils require tevila without a brocha when the dishes or vessels are made from glazed china, bone china, stoneware, corning ware, or porcelain enamel.
>
> Other vessels requiring tevila without a brocha include: Utensils made from a combination of materials, e.g. metal pots coated with teflon or enamel...

From the [Kof-K website](https://www.kof-k.org/articles/040108090413W-3%20Tevilas%20Keilim.pdf):

> Although Enamel is a glass like substance, there is a dispute among the poskim if this item should be toveled at all. Therefore, one should tovel Enamel utensils without a beracha.